# Streaming video with ip camera also record it

Tags: php, video, video-streaming, html5-video, live-streaming

I have a website page and i need to stream a video online at specific time for one hour and after finish save this video on pc..Let's say starting time is 10:00am , ending time is 11:00am, during this hour the streaming video running on the website as live video after time up save this as a video on my pc. Is it possible to do this using php? And if not how can i do that?. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i've same problem with you and got nothing yet. so i have solution for my problem. when streaming video running, i capture that video and save it to database using interval function. to capture that video i use [htlm2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and make autosave function. i hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done, I have tried by displaying it on the website and storing it in the website folder, you can see it on [www.puritycode.net](https://www.puritycode.net) but I use asp.net mvc, but this application does not work on Android and iOS browsers, I am trying to be able to solve it